# WAMP requires curl.cainfo certficate in order to work with Pusher

Tags: laravel, wamp, pusher, ca

I'm working in **WAMP** and **Laravel** on localhost. I was trying to broadcast an event using **Pusher** to my font end and Laravel was throwing an exception. I fixed the issue by downloading **cainfo** certficate from **curl** official website and setting **curl.cainfo** variable in **php.ini** to point to downloaded certificate. I was wondering why is this required? Is this only for WAMP or only for Pusher? Or it's because Pusher is using **HTTPS**?

Comment: It's required so php's curl implementation knows which certificates are trusted, just like your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Is it only for the PHP you're using in your Wamp to connect with services who requires SSL.. 
- download it from here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
- Add it to your ssl folder in your php version, and modify your php.ini files (in Wamp folder and PHP folder): 
 curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp\bin\php{php_version}\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"